# React native run-android issue

Tags: android, react-native

To run `yarn run android` on an existing project I am getting this below error

> > java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)

but if I remove below code form build.gradle

`exec {
     commandLine 'security', '-q', 'find-generic-password', '-a', 
      currentUser, '-s', keyChain, '-w'
      standardOutput = stdout
      errorOutput = stderr
      ignoreExitValue true
     }`

and run the ./gradlew --debug it returns build

> BUILD SUCCESSFUL

After again if I run

> yarn run android

I am getting this below error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
What went wrong: 
Execution failed for task ':app:processDevDebugGoogleServices'.
File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin 
cannot function without it.
```

Do you have any idea Why I am getting this error?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like You are using Google services in your app. You need to obtain a json file from Google developers website.

Comment: @Rubelhasan Can you upvote my comment if it helped? It will be really great if you do. Thanks